# Show that $S_n/n$ converges almost surely if $S_{2^n}/2^n$ converges almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X_n$ be independent random variables such that $\dfrac{S_n}{n}\to0$ in probability and $\dfrac{S_{2^n}}{2^n}\to0$ almost surely. Show that, $\dfrac{S_n}{n}\to0$ almost surely. Here $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$.

I proceeded as follows:

> For each positive integer $n$ there exists $k_n$ such that $2^{k_n}\leq n<2^{k_n+1}$. Now, $$\dfrac{S_n}{n}=\dfrac{S_{2^{k_n}}+\sum_{j=2^{k_n}+1}^nX_j}{n}=\dfrac{S_{2^{k_n}}}{n}+\dfrac{\sum_{j=2^{k_n}+1}^nX_j}{n}$$
>   The first term goes to $0$ (keeping in mind $2^{k_n}<n$). However I am having trouble with the second term. Also I am not able to exploit the independence nicely.

Please provide a "hint" only and NOT an answer.

Comment: Hint: Kolmogorov's $0-1$ Law

Comment: Hi!! The reason I didn't comment is I thought I would read up the law and see if I can do it myself. However, it seems this problem and the law are quite orthogonal. Any more hint, please? :(

Comment: i had some arguments in my head on how to prove your claim using the 0-1 law but when I actually sat down to write it out, I couldn't do it. But something about this claim seems off to me.  Convergence in probability implies a.s. convergence along a subsequence. But the claim gives an extra specific subsequence along which a.s. convergence occurs and I don't see what is special about this subsequence.

Comment: I give an argument here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195885/a-criterion-of-convergence-almost-surely